# Bash: Look for files in certain folders and then create output lists

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to Bash, and I'm trying to find files in a certain set of folders. I want to create a txt report for image files in each /check/ folder.

Here's what I've been working with:

```
# Find images
for f in */check/ ; do
    find ./ -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" > find_images.txt
        echo "finished $f"
done
```

I can't figure out how to only look at subfolders named "check", and I also want to pass the variable so that I get separate text files named after the parent folders. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `find "$f"` rather than `find ./` if you want to search the `check` directory from the `for` loop. You'd also have to fix the redirect in that case, to avoid continually overwriting the same `find_images.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you're not using `$f` which contains the folder's name:

```
# Find images
for f in */check/ ; do
    # Removing front-slashes from $f to use in log name
    # http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion
    log_f="${f//\//_}"

    # Only search inside $f, saving results to find_images_[foldername].txt
    find "$f" -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" > "find_images_${log_f}.txt"

    echo "finished $f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **grep command** and pipe it with **find command**

```
find . | grep check
```

Comment: `find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\|jpeg\)" | grep check`

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command supports searching for directories (folders), e.g.

```
find . -name "check" -type d
```

You could use these results to then look for the files you want. The variable $f will be the name of the folder, so use that in the inner find command.  Then if you want separate output files each time through the loop, use a variable in the filename. The $f variable will have slashes in the content, so you probably don't want to use that in the name of your output file. In my example, I use a counter to make sure each output file has a unique name.

```
count=1
for f in `find . -name "check" -type d` ; do
    find $f -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" > find_images_$count_.txt
    count=$((count+1))
done
```