# Bash: List directories with a type of file, but missing another type of file

Tags: bash, find, command

I'm new(ish) to using Bash and I'm trying to figure out how to combine a few different things into one script.

I'm looking for file transfers that were interrupted. These folders contain image files (either jpgs or pngs), but are missing another specific file (finished.txt).

Here is what I'm using to find folders with images (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932343/bash-look-for-files-in-certain-folders-and-then-create-output-lists)):

```
for f in */incoming/ ; do
    log_f="${f//\//}"
    echo "searching $f"
    find "$f" -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" > "/output/${log_f}.txt"
    echo "$f finished"
done
```

Then, I'm running this command to find folders that are missing the finished.txt file (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file)):

```
find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d '!' -exec test -e "{}/finished.txt" ';' -print
```

Is there a way to combine them so I have a list of folders which have jpg or png files, but *don't* have finished.txt? Also, If I want to add -mtime, where do I put that?

Alternatively, if there's a better/faster way to do this, I'm interested in that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the first pass when you get the files with jpg/png you can get the directory by using dirname. The list of directories can then be used for iterating over and looking for finished.txt file. On finding you can skip the directory if not print it out.

Something as below should do the needful

```
for i in `find "$f" -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" -exec dirname {} \;`
do 
    ls  $i | grep finished >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then 
        echo $i 
    fi 
done
```

Add " | sort | uniq" at the end of find command to perhaps remove the duplicates. Something like

find "$f" -iname "*jpg*" -o -iname "*png*" -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason, I'm getting this:

`find: ‘’: No such file or directory`

Comment: I hope you are setting f which is parameterized in the above command "$f". So something like f=/Users/guest/mydirectory, followed by running the above command.